# sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable PROBLEM

Tags: 22.04, ppa, add-apt-repository, touchegg

I want to install touchegg because I'm on x11, but when I write:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:touchegg/stable`

I get this:

```
Repository: 'deb https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/touchegg/stable/ubuntu/ jammy main'
Description:
Latest stable version of Touchégg for all Ubuntu flavours.

Touchégg is an app that runs in the background and transform the gestures you make on your touchpad or touchscreen into visible actions in your desktop. Learn more at https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg
More info: https://launchpad.net/~touchegg/+archive/ubuntu/stable
Adding repository.
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel.
Found existing deb entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding deb entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Found existing deb-src entry in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Adding disabled deb-src entry to /etc/apt/sources.list.d/touchegg-ubuntu-stable-jammy.list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 364, in <module>
    sys.exit(0 if addaptrepo.main() else 1)
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 357, in main
    shortcut.add()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 222, in add
    self.add_key()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/shortcuthandler.py", line 398, in add_key
    if not all((self.trustedparts_file, self.trustedparts_content)):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 141, in trustedparts_content
    key = self.lpppa.getSigningKeyData()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/resource.py", line 592, in __call__
    response, content = self.root._browser._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/lazr/restfulclient/_browser.py", line 429, in _request
    raise error
lazr.restfulclient.errors.ServerError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
Response headers:
---
connection: close
content-length: 30
content-type: text/plain;charset=utf-8
date: Mon, 26 Jun 2023 17:59:18 GMT
server: gunicorn
status: 500
x-lazr-oopsid: OOPS-cf0f902216042af99f25d4c45dded3ae
x-powered-by: Zope (www.zope.org), Python (www.python.org)
x-request-id: 7ffde6e7-cccf-4682-9f21-8ad74dd49768
x-vcs-revision: aedf8597c50c1abc5fb7f9e871e686dfcb381fde
---
Response body:
---
b'GPGKeyTemporarilyNotFoundError'
---
```

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same issue with an exact same error message as a response body.

Adding the key manually worked for me as I found it at [link:Add PPA for jammy errors on key fetch](https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg/issues/578#issuecomment-1109867038)

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C0FCE32AF6B96252
```